# "Tonight let's go with the bottle of Cabernet *vs.* the Merlot."

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, latin

(Note that the home wine rack has 10 different kinds of wine in it.)

I've been told now and again over the years that this kind of use of **vs.** (versus) is improper.  Apparently it's supposed to only be used in situations with combative opposites, *where only two are contesting* and only one expected to be victorious.  (e.g. Dodgers vs. Giants - - and I don't think this has anything to do with the abbreviation, so for the purposes of this post I'll assume the full word and abbreviation are one and the same.)

Perhaps clunky and less than optimal, but is the example improper use?  Or is it just a matter of style that irritates a select few who have well defined/informed opinions – or pedants – like using a *serial comma* can set-off someone on a passionate diatribe ridiculing the *Strunk and White* book.

Or maybe I'm missing here the specific faux pas people have mentioned.  Perhaps someone can gather and explain what it is and I'll change the post to reflect the “bad” use.

Comment: I don't see a problem. It does perhaps imply a larger context wherein the pros and cons of the two alternatives are being set off against each other. But I'd say there's no need to get that serious about it. Happy day.

Comment: If only two options are being seriously considered (regardless of how many second-tier candidates there are), *vs.* is appropriate, as they are in opposition.

Comment: "Improper" is a judgment of etiquette, not of language. If people use it (and they do) then it is part of the language. If style authorities object to it (and it appears they do) then those who follow the authorities will object to it.

Comment: I think your wine example uses *versus* to mean "instead of" or "as opposed to."  In my mind *versus* doesn't quite mean that and I suspect that's why some people object.  But it's a very fine distinction because there had been two things battling it out in your head- it was "the Cab" vs "the Merlot" and the Cab won so you announced it. So while I would never say anything to you about your word choice were I your friend, I'd also never say that myself.

Comment: The problem is that in my mind, and in the minds of many other speakers, *versus* essentially means *against*, whereas in your use it means *instead of, rather than*.

Comment: I don't think I'm supposed to use comments to thank people, but special thanks to _Jim_ and _Anonym_ for **explaining** the opposing point of view, which helps me understand, … vs. just getting the correct answer. ;-)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The last time I typed "A word versus a different word" into Google, the immediate response was **"Did you mean: 'Word' *vs* 'Different Word'"** with the "vs" in italics and no period following it. Thus it has become standard usage for a lot of native English speakers and writers.

Of course I assume you still say "versus" when you make such a statement. To make it clear to English language learners, it would **not** be appropriate to say, **"Cabernet 'vee-ess' the Merlot."**

Comment: It might help me be a better forum member if down-voters explained why my answer is unacceptable. (I have already attempted to delete my answer due to receiving four down-votes so far.) I thought the fact that Google treats the word "versus" as though it were misspelled is linguistically significant enough to mention. My original search, which is how I discovered the existence of EL&U, was for "meme versus trope," to which Google responded, "Did you mean: 'meme *vs* trope'?"

Comment: In my reading of it, your answer is not an answer. At best, it suggests that Google's analytics have determined that people write "vs" more often than "versus", at least on the internet. This is a rather tangential comment, I'd say (and would have been better posted as a comment). It doesn't really provide any information towards answering the question of whether it's acceptable to say "versus" when you mean something like "instead of" or "rather than", which seems to be what the OP is really asking. But no matter now. The question's on hold anyway.

Comment: I read his question differently, but his edits of December 25, 2015 and your comment make it clear that I was mistaken. Thank you, @RJH, for taking the time to explain it to me. I appreciate it.